# JavaFX Task vs plain old Thread, what are the differences?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task

Aside from the properties to know the state of the task and the call backs (completed, failed, etc), is there any other differences of using JavaFX Task over a plain old Java Thread with a lambda?

I'm not asking what's good or bad, I'm not asking what you think I should do, I'm asking for the objective factual differences that would happen when using a Task instead of a plain lambda to run a background thread in a JavaFX application. Aside from the the differences that I already mentioned.

On the Oracel's tutorial for concurrency, in the section titled "Why Use the javafx.concurrent Package?" it says:

> If you have special requirements or need extra power over the code, implementing a background worker by creating a Runnable object and a new thread is an appropriate way to go.

other than that, all the reasons for using a `Task` are equally applicable to a `Runnable` and I don't see what special requirements or extra power one gains, I also don't see what you lose, if anything, aside from state and callbacks, when choosing `Runnable` over `Task`. What I do see is that using `Task` is much more verbose:

```
new Thread(this::doSomething).start();
```

vs

```
new Thread(new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        doSomething();
        return null;
    }
}).start();
```

My concern would be the some unexpected side effect from choosing a shorter more concise version of the code that according to Oracle, should only be used in special cases.

`doSomething` is a variety of different activity on this example and I'm interested in facts that are agnostic to what they do. In my case, it's mostly network requests that then update the UI by using `Platoform.runLater`.

Comment: Really? downvotes and no comments? _sigh_

Comment: What kind of answers are you expecting? It is what it is - a more convenient way for UI-aware multithreading in JavaFX. I can't think off the top of my head of pros/cons other than what can be glimpsed from the documentation, so for me its more a question of scale and style preference.

Comment: I like how calls to the `update*()` methods "are coalesced and run later on the FX application thread," but the convenience is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I am late to this discussion/fist-fight, but isn't this question primarily opinion-based, or at least prone to lead to a discussion instead of a definitive answer? For novices, the advantages you already mention might be huge anyway. The state-management (particularly in the context of a `ScheduledService`, for example) are not completely trivial. For me, it was not at all obvious how you would implement the functionality @trashgod mentions, but for others that might be trivial too, and amount to API bloat.

Comment: It seems a bit ridiculous to make this comment to someone with your reputation, but since this is not the first question I've seen from you that has attracted downvotes (and your comments seem to indicate you don't know why), perhaps it would behove you to take (or presumably revisit) the [tour]? It makes several points that may improve your questions: "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." ... "Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion", etc.

Comment: @Pablo As a 90k+ rep user of over 9 years of this site and nearly 600 questions, you ought to know what kind of questions are OK to ask by now. This question is broad and opinion-laden. Stack Overflow isn't a site for pro vs con lists.

Comment: What a class provides is not opinion based. Whether you think is good or not is opinion based. For example, if the JavaFX Task does something special with caught exceptions (like log them), there's nothing opinion based about it. That's a fact. Whether you think logging uncaught exceptions is a good thing or not it's opinion.

Comment: @Pablo Whether or not it's an "advantage", which is what you actually asked, is the same as whether it is (relatively) "good", which by your own argument is opinion-based. Even if you simply want an enumeration of what a class provides, then any answer would simply be a regurgitation of the API docs for `Task` - what would be the point in that? It is clearly the opinion of the SO community that this question is off-topic. Either improve it, or find a discussion forum to post things like this.

Comment: Fair enough, I removed "advantage".

Comment: OK, so now how is this different from asking us to reiterate the API docs, which list the functionality a `Task` provides over a `Runnable`? At best you have changed the reason for closing from "opinion-based" to "too broad". Again, I quote: "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.". Your question bears absolutely no resemblance to the kinds of questions that are supported here.

Comment: @James_D because that's not what I'm after. I already read the documentation for Task and the description of why one should use Task applies equally to a Runnable and there's no explanation of why one should use a Task over a Runnable if one doesn't care about those extra features, which I already listed in the question as know and accounted for and now what I'm after. What I'm after is the deeper difference that might not be apparent. And yes, this is not an error-kind of problem but a decision kind of problem.

Comment: @Pablo Your question is off-topic. Sorry if this site does not provide what you are after.

Comment: @James_D yeah, it's very disappointing that Stack Overflow swallowed the popularity of most online communities making them die, only to tighten the definition of what's acceptable making many questions and conversations not have a place to be. It's like Walmart putting out of business smaller more specialized shops and not carrying what they used to carry.

Comment: The latest edit produces a question that probably wouldn't be closed (though to answer it I'd have to make a lot of guesses about what you're doing in `updateIdentity()`, and it's still quite broad).

Comment: @James_D I changed `updateIdenitity()` to something more generic and added a paragraph about it.

Comment: I nominated for reopening.

Comment: Thank you @James_D, I appreciate it.

Comment: I personally find it quite embarrassing that this community scoffs at any question that doesn't strictly conform to the narrow guidelines of what constitutes a good question. I think that this is worthy of discussion-- I see no worthwhile benefit to using `Task` over a `Runnable` implementation. `Task` is more verbose and it generally makes the process of writing test code more involved to the point where third-party libraries exist just for that purpose.

Comment: One of the most upvoted questions for Java asks whether Java is pass-by-reference or pass-by-value. One can find the answer for themselves by writing 10 lines of code, or looking in the Java Language Specification, which also gives the answer. If that's worth over 5000 upvotes for what is essentially regurgitating the JLS, perhaps this is also worthy of some thought. What has happened in this comment section is overly-pedantic behavior that replaced what could have been a good discussion. Perhaps this would be more welcomed on a site that actively encourages discussion.

Comment: I had encountered the same dillema today and can't find an answer for it anywhere. I wrote to moderator to reopen.